# How To Use UserData to Save From One ViewController To Another - Reminders XCode Swift

Tags: swift, database, xcode, userdefaults

I currently have two view controllers - one which displays all the reminders in a table and another which is where you set the actual reminder ie, title and date. What I understand and have done so far is placed the userdata from the set reminders page in a key and hence stored the value. What I do not seem to understand is how to link and display that on my actual reminders page on the table cells so that it is saved.

I would appreciate all types of feedback and help. Thank you.

Reminders Page Code:

```
import UserNotifications
import UIKit

class RemindersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    
    var models = [MyReminder]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapAdd() {
        
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "add") as? SetReminderViewController else {
            
            return
            
        }
        
        vc.title = "New Reminder"
        vc.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        vc.completion = {title, date in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                let new = MyReminder(title: title, date: date, identifier: "id_\(title)")
                self.models.append(new)
                self.table.reloadData()
                
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                      content.title = title
                      content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
                    let targetDate = date
                      let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: targetDate), repeats: false)
                      
                      let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "requestid", content: content, trigger: trigger)
                      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
                          
                          if error != nil {
                              print("Something went wrong")
                          }
                          
                      })
            }
        }
    
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
           return 1
        
       }
       
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
           return models.count
        
       }
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Reminders"
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          if (editingStyle == .delete) {
              models.remove(at: indexPath.item)
              tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
              
          }
      }
    
    
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
           cell.textLabel?.text = models [indexPath.row].title
            let date = models[indexPath.row].date
        
        
         let formatter = DateFormatter()
             formatter.dateFormat = "E, MMM d, h:mm a"
             cell.detailTextLabel?.text = formatter.string(from: date)
             return cell
       }
    
}

struct MyReminder {
    let title: String
    let date: Date
    let identifier: String
}
```

Set Reminders Code:

```
import UIKit

class SetReminderViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var titleField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults()

    public var completion: ((String, Date) -> Void)?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleField.delegate = self
        
        userDefaults.value(forKey: "title")
        userDefaults.value(forKey: "date")

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(didTapSaveButton))
        
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
                
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneClicked))
        
        toolBar.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)
        
        titleField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
                
        datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
    
        
    }

    @objc func didTapSaveButton() {
        
        if let titleText = titleField.text, !titleText.isEmpty {
            let targetDate = datePicker.date
            
            completion?(titleText, targetDate)
            
            userDefaults.setValue(titleField.text, forKeyPath: "title")
            userDefaults.setValue(datePicker.date, forKeyPath: "date")

        }
    }
    
    @objc func doneClicked() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SetReminderViewController you always overwrite the title and date key paths in user defaults. So your first reminder will be overridden by your second one. You should store them in some kind of an array.

Make your MyReminder model Codable which allows you to store your models in UserDefaults:

```swift
struct MyReminder: Codable {
    let title: String
    let date: Date
    let identifier: String
}
```

For retrieving and storing your reminders you could change the models property in RemindersViewController:

```swift
var models: [MyReminder] {
    get {
        // Retrieve data from user defaults or return an empty array
        guard
            let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "reminders"),
            let reminders = try? JSONDecoder().decode([MyReminder].self, from: data)
        else {
            return []
        }
        return reminders
    }
    set {
        // Store data in user defaults when encoding succeeds
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) else { return }
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(data, forKey: "reminders")
    }
}
```

Now that your models property handles all the user defaults logic you can remove that logic from SetReminderViewController:

```swift
// Remove these
userDefaults.setValue(titleField.text, forKeyPath: "title")
userDefaults.setValue(datePicker.date, forKeyPath: "date")
```

That's it now your reminders will be automatically stored in user defaults once you append a new entry to your models property. And when you reopen your app the reminders will be fetched from the user defaults.